# Changing the format/layout of an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, layout, format, spreadsheet

I have a worksheet with over 3 months worth of data entry.  My coworker claims she can't understand the layout.  She wants me to change it from example 1 to example 2.  Is there any easy way to do this without re-entering 3 months worth of work?

Example 1

```
WK# | DATE       | ACCT NAME                        
1   | 7/09/15    | MY PLACE                     
2   | 8/06/15    | MY PLACE                     
3   | 8/13/15    | MY PLACE                     
4   | 8/20/15    | MY PLACE                     
5   | 8/27/15    | MY PLACE
```

Example 2

```
Acct Name  |    Wk 1   |    Wk 2   |    Wk 3    |   Wk 4    |   Wk 5    |
-----------|-----------|-----------|------------|-----------|-----------|
My Place   |    7/9/15 |    8/6/15 |    8/13/15 |   8/20/15 |   8/27/15 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.

For every processing worksheet:

1. [Create new worksheet](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0097.html)
2. [Populate layout (header) cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) of new created worksheet
3. [Read cell values from old worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148765/getting-values-from-other-sheet-in-excel-using-vba) and put these values to the new worksheet cells.