# Assign the numeric value of a cell to an integer variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have numeric values on specific cells, the cell's row and column are known. I want to assign the numeric values in these cells to an integer variable in my code that I could then modify and use to update the same cell.

I have tried using the following codes but they did not work because when I add my variables to watch, the value of my variables remained as 0 even the cells have non zero numbers.

```
    Dim GetTableCount as Integer

    GetTableCount = Cells(17, 13).value        
    GetTableCount = CInt(Cells(17, 13).value)  
    GetTableCount = Range(M17)
    GetTableCount = Range(M17).value 
    GetTableCount = CInt(Range(M17).value)
    GetTableCount = CInt(Range(M17))
```

I have also tried using the index function but I failed on looking up the right syntax.
My last attempt to solve the problem is to specify the cells to "Numbers" format instead of "General" but still nothing.

Comment: It's `Range("M17")` unless you have a variable named `M17` which hold a range address.   `GetTableCount = CInt(Cells(17, 13).Value)` should work. If you're debugging, you have to step *past* the assignment before `GetTableCount` will indicate a value.

Comment: `GetTableCount = Val([M17])`

Comment: There is no M17 variable in my code.

I have tried overstepping through this line
GetTableCount = CInt(Cells(17, 13).Value)
But the value on debug mode is still 0, and not the value of the cell that I specified.

I will double check this again tomorrow.

Comment: None of these will work if you are interrogating a worksheet that is not the active one. Try putting a `With ... End With` block around your code, eg `With Worksheets("Sheet1")|GetTableCount = .Cells(17,13).Value`

Comment: `@Ambie`, you are right , I did have these codes prior to assigning the cell value to my variables:
    `Sheets("ADMIN").Visible = True`
    `Sheets("ADMIN").Select` where the ADMIN sheet is where I place my integer values in a cell,
`@Tim @Slai` but still none of the solutions work.

Comment: It turns out that `anyintvar = Cells(row, column)` works but the code is reading it from a different worksheet so the value remains at 0, with the cell from wherever sheet the code is reading seems to be empty. Even I had these lines for sheet selections `Sheets("ADMIN").Visible = True` and `Sheets("ADMIN").Select` the code still does not  read from the selected sheet. Using this: `GetTableCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ADMIN").Cells(17, 13)` fixed the problem. I did not even have to write these lines anymore  `Sheets("ADMIN").Visible = True` `Sheets("ADMIN").Select` kudos to @jpinto3912

Comment: Thank you for helping out Tim, Slai and Ambie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that

> `anyintvar = Cells(row, column)`

works but the code is reading it from a different worksheet so the value remains at 0, with the cell from wherever sheet the code is reading seems to be empty.

Even though I had these lines for sheet selections

> `Sheets("ADMIN").Visible = True`
>
> `Sheets("ADMIN").Select`

the code still does not read from the selected sheet.

Using this however:

> `GetTableCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ADMIN").Cells(rownumber, columnnumber)`

fixed the problem. I did not even have to write the pervious two lines anymore. Kudos to @jpinto3912 [Page where I found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148765/getting-values-from-other-sheet-in-excel-using-vba)