# Get Values from Cells from other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I was make a small VBA code which  get me a list with all sheets names from my workbook,  My question is:
How can I get values from Sheet7 ("B4:B5"),Sheet8 ("B4:B5"),Sheet ("B4:B5") ..... into Sheet6 which is present the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Call task
End Sub
Sub task()
Call ThisWorkbook.speedOn
    Dim pws As Worksheet
    Dim x, N As Integer
    Dim browLastCol As Range
    Set pws = Sheets("Sheet6")
    'Set browLastCol = pws.Range(Cells(3, 4), Cells(3, 4).End(xlToRight))
    Set browLastCol = pws.Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(9, 2).End(xlDown))
    
        x = 9
        
        pws.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 2).End(xlToRight)).Clear

 
   For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
     If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
       If ws.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
            If ws.Name <> "Sheet4" Then
             If ws.Name <> "Sheet5" Then
               If ws.Name <> "Sheet6" Then
               
                    Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(x, 2) = ws.Name ' List woksheets name 
                    
                     x = x + 1
                      Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A3").RowHeight = 40
                      
                      
                      With browLastCol
                               .RowHeight = 26
                               'Some code removed
                     End With
                      
                     
                 End If
                End If
             End If
         End If
      End If
   End If
Next ws
 Call ThisWorkbook.speedOff
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get values from other sheet using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148765/get-values-from-other-sheet-using-vba)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should find the answer to this question already exists in multiple places. Please read this blog post on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already shared a duplicate solution, but I would consider using `Select Case` here to get rid of all of those `IF` statements.

```
For Each ws in Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6"
            'Do Nothing (leave this blank)
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(x, 2) = ws.Name 
            x = x + 1
            Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A3").RowHeight = 40

            With browLastCol
                .RowHeight = 26
                'Some code removed
            End With

    End Select
Next ws
```